# Find the Galois group of $x^4-12x^2+8x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, discriminant, quartics

I want to find the Galois group of $x^4-12x^2+8x$. What is the standard method to do this?

Is it to find resolvant cubic and its discriminant? If it is a perfect -$A_3$. If not- $S_3$?

Many thanks

---

**Edit:**
Let $f(x)=x^4-12x^2+8x=xg(x)$ where $g(x)=x^3-12x+8$ is irreducible by Eisenstein using $p=2$

Comment: IIRC you can't use Eisenstein as 4 divide 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to find the Galois group of the splitting field of this polynomial over the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. There is a general method to find the Galois group of the splitting field of a third degree polynomial.

Let $L$ be the splitting field of the irreducible polynomial of degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$. You can show that if $\sqrt{\Delta} \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=3$, so the Galois group is the cyclic group of order 3.  Otherwise, if $\sqrt{\Delta}\notin \mathbb{Q}$ we get $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ and therefore Galois group $S_3$.

Comment: So say if we have a quartic polynomial which can be decomposed into a linear factor multiplied with an irreducible cubic polynomial. Do we then just work using this cubic polynomial? Also... what about the cubic resolvent?

Comment: The splitting field of a polynomial $f$  over a field $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field $\mathbb{Q}(a_1,...a_n)$ where $a_1,...,a_n$ are the roots of $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Since the linear factor has as root an element in $\mathbb{Q}$, so  this does not extend the field. Therefore you can just calculate the splitting field of the cubic polynomial. 
I do not see a reason to use the cubic resolvent. By the way, you can not use Eisenstein here, since $2^2| 8$.

Comment: ok thank you, it is starting to make more sense now

Comment: Also, do we not also have to consider $A_3$?

Comment: $A_3$ is equal to the cyclic group of order 3, so we already considered it.